# FPDF: different header logo

Tags: php, header, fpdf

I use the FPDF Class in PHP to create PDFs. All works well, but now I need the PDF with different logos in the header.

Creating a header works well.

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
  function Footer() {
    // some code
  }

  function Header() {
    $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header.png', 0, 0, 215);
  }
}
```

Now I need something like this. The variable "$is_summer" exists in my file.

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
  function Footer() {
    // some code
  }

  function Header() {
    if ($is_summer)
      $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_summer.png', 0, 0, 215);
    } else {
      $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_winter.png', 0, 0, 215);
    }
  }
}
```

But I get: *Notice: Undefined variable: is_summer in createPDFpriv.php on line 200*.

Ok, undefined var. So I tried

```
function Header($is_summer) {
  if ($is_summer)
    $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_summer.png', 0, 0, 215);
  } else {
    $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_winter.png', 0, 0, 215);
  }
}
```

Another error: *Warning: Declaration of PDF::Header($is_summer) should be compatible with FPDF::Header() in createPDFpriv.php on line 145*

Also tried:

```
 if ($is_summer) {
   function Header() {
     $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_summer.png', 0, 0, 215);
   }
 } else {
   function Header() {
     $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_winter.png', 0, 0, 215);
   }
 }
```

Also an error: *parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in createPDFpriv.php on line 199*. Ok, there is a function expected, this doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You must declare your variable globaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have forgotten " $this " before " is_summer "? You can try this :

```js
class PDF extends FPDF{

 private $isSummer = false;
 function __construct($summer) {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->isSummer = $summer;
  print "In BaseClass constructor\n";
 }

 function Header() {
  if ($this->isSummer) {
   $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_summer.png', 0, 0, 215);
  } else {
   $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_winter.png', 0, 0, 215);
  }
 }
}
```

and when using it :

```js
$mysummer = true; // or false
$mypdf = new PDF($mysummer);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me to solve the problem and it works with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it like this:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
  public  $is_summer;
  function Footer() {
    // some code
  }

  function Header() {
    if ($this->is_summer)
      $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_summer.png', 0, 0, 215);
    } else {
      $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_winter.png', 0, 0, 215);
    }
  }
}
```

So what you'd do is when you make the PDF object, you set the `is_summer` property to true or false, and it'll be able to use that property in your `Header` function.

To do this, you can make a constructor function like so:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
  public  $is_summer;
  function __construct($is_summer){
    $this->is_summer = $is_summer;
  }
  function Footer() {
    // some code
  }

  function Header() {
    if ($this->is_summer)
      $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_summer.png', 0, 0, 215);
    } else {
      $this->Image('PDF/images/pdf_header_winter.png', 0, 0, 215);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It helps me to understand and to solve the problem.